# c++11 std::move thread function

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to make this piece of code work but i can't understood where I'm wrong
the following code won't print the "foo" and the "here I'm" strings

```
class scoped_thread
{
std::thread t;
public:
explicit scoped_thread(std::thread t_):t(std::move(t_))
{
    std::cout<<"here I'm"<<std::endl;
    if(!t.joinable())
        throw std::logic_error("No thread");
}

~scoped_thread()
{

    t.join();
}

scoped_thread(scoped_thread const&)=delete;
scoped_thread& operator=(scoped_thread const&)=delete;
};


void foo(){
std::cout<<"foo"<<std::endl;    
}

scoped_thread t1(std::thread(foo));
```

it simply won't execute the constructor.

if I change the last lines to

```
class foo1{
public:
void foo(){
    std::cout<<"foo"<<std::endl;    
}

}

scoped_thread t1(std::thread(&foo1::foo,&foo1));
```

the thread foo start to work.

i'm using mingw 4.8.1 and c++11 flag of the compiler
where I'm wrong? I'have tried to figure what constructor must I use but up to now I haven't found it

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6926958e1eec7cc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the Most Vexing Parse.

Basically the compiler treats `scoped_thread t1(std::thread(foo));` as a function declaration (declaring a function with a single `std::thread` argument named `foo`). It can be either a function declaration or a variable definition, but the rules of the language state that anything that can be both is a function declaration.

The traditional fix has been to add extra parentheses, like so `scoped_thread t1((std::thread(foo)));` making it so that it cannot be parsed as a function declaration anymore. With C++ you can also use list-initialization instead, which doesn't fall prey to the Most Vexing Parse (though it has its own issues), like so `scoped_thread t1{std::thread(foo)};`.

Comment: thank you very much! I forgot this detail I have read in a book.

Comment: Wouldn't this also work: `scoped_thread t1 = scoped_thread(std::thread(foo));` ?

Comment: In this case, no, because the class is not movable, but if it was it would work, yes.